# How can I change the fields within a struct by n?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bitmap, file-pointer

Here's the struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize; //size increases if n > 1
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

Here's some of the other code I'm already dealing with:

```
// read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

// read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

// ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
    bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
{
    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
    return 4;
}

if (n < 1 || n > 100)
{
    printf("Please enter a value between 1 and 100\n");
}

// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);
```

When the user enters an argument between 1 and 100, I'd like for bfSize to increase * n.

Comment: `bf.bfSize *= n;`?

Comment: Okay, wow, you've gotta be kidding me.

I was doing BITMAPFILEHEADER.bfSize *= n and was getting "expected identifier or '('
    BITMAPFILEHEADER.bfSize *= n;" when I compiled the code.

I'm an idiot.

Comment: Note you also have to change width and height in `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, and you have to adjust for padding. Then there is the task of dealing with the bits. You might want to look for a graphics library which does all this. There is lots of options to choose from.

Comment: This is for an Intro To Comp-Sci course I'm taking (CS50 if you're familiar with that), so I think I need to do this by hand. Would bi.biWidth *= n work like the bfSize example?

Comment: If width and height are multiplied by 2, then size is multiplied by 4. Just calculate the new width and height, then `size = width * height * 3` where `3` is the number bytes for each pixel (in a 24-bit image)

Comment: You make it seem like it'll be really easy, but I'm worried writing this code out will be a bit more complicated.